# How to record top 5 values in struct

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, struct

I have this struct below

```
struct Income
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    double income;
};
struct World
{
    Income people[100];
} myWorld;
```

And i wish to print and display the top 5 incomes by first and last name.

What would be a good way to sort and read through the incomes and print those with the top 5 incomes by names?

Lets say i have 100 values in this struct.

Comment: `std::partial_sort` with custom comparator?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `std::sort` which takes a compare function, something like:

```
 #include <algorithm>
 using namespace std;

 vector<Income> v;
 for (auto i : myWorld.people) {
    v.push_back(i);
}

 sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const Income& i, const Income& j) { return i.income > j.income; });
```

Then simply print the first 5, something like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5;  ++i) {
    cout << v[i].firstname << " " << v[i].lastname << endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: You need `using namespace std;`

Comment: Yeah i included algorithm, still getting that issue though.

Comment: I am using using 'namespace std; ' also